# Estimate the off balance sheet exposures of a banking book, based on limited data

Tags: finance, banks, accounting, exposure

I am doing an analysis on Off Balance sheet items on a bank. Only data I have is authorized amount and outstanding balance for all the loans the bank currently has.
Can  I simply take the difference of the authorized amount and the OS balance as the off balance sheet exposure?

What am I missing here? Are there any ways to estimate the off balance sheet exposures that I am missing ,based on this simple approach?